# Open dot-file with dialogue in OSX

Tags: macos, .htaccess

Since the GUI-side of OSX treats all dot-files (such as `.htaccess`) as hidden, it doesn't display them in any of the graphical UI:s, e.g. Finder or the Open-dialogues.

How can I open a dot-file (`.htaccess` in this case) in a graphical editor, without doing [that thing](http://lifehacker.com/software/command-line/show-hidden-files-in-finder-188892.php) for all hidden files, universally and without going through Terminal.app?

*Edit:* I'm on Leopard, if that makes a difference.

*Edit2:* TextWrangler and TextMate seem to have features that allow you to open hidden files, which *partly* answers my question.

Comment: Why not do that thing you linked to? It's always one of the first things I do on a fresh OS X install.

Comment: Because I don't like how the files are cluttered literally everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried dharmabruce's answer on Lion. It worked for me, and it seems to be just the answer you were looking for.

Comment: @HenrikPaul Please accept dharmabruce's answer. Works perfectly

Answer (score 22):

In an "Open File" dialog you can use Command-Shift-. to see dot files.

Comment: Worked for me on Lion. Amazing tip, I'd upvote more if I could.

Answer (score 3):

You could tell Finder to display hidden files as well (enter in Terminal):

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

But that’s not really nice since there are a lot more hidden files. So I recommend to use an editor that allows you to view those in the open dialog like Chuck mentioned.

Comment: You can use onyx to do this without the terminal.

Comment: Sure, there are a couple other ways to do this such as Secrets <http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-secrets/> or the Property List Editor (bundled with Xcode).

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to do this for one specific file, you can create a symbolic link to the dot-file.  Open up Terminal.app, cd to the directory containing your dot-file, and run

```
ln -s .htaccess dot_htaccess
```

Then you should be able to double-click the file `dot_htaccess` as a regular file, and any edits you make will really go into .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

TextMate (a really nice text editor for OS X) open dialog has a "Show hidden files" option, and TextWrangler (and its big brother BBEdit) has it has a menu item.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't use TextMate, but mainly NetBeans (and occasionally Smultron/TextWrangler) :/

Comment: I can't speak to NetBeans, but I believe TextWrangler also has an "Open Hidden" option.

Comment: Would you look at that. I never noticed the separate open-dialogue (I always use cmd-o)

Answer (score 1):

In the command line, for a file named FILE, type:

```
open -e FILE
```

The open command will open the file in TextEdit (-e flag).  Check out "man open" for more flags (e.g., specify the app to open with -a)

Answer (score 1):

Smultron (another nice OS X editor mentioned in the comment above and similar to TextMate, but free) has an "Open Hidden..." file menu item that works splendidly for this purpose.

Sad news: Smultron is apparently no longer being developed further beyond v3.5.1 (which requires Leopard), according to a post from its author at its homepage: http://tuppis.com/smultron/

jEdit is another free option that has hidden file support: www.jedit.org/users-guide/vfs-browser.html  (sorry for the lack of 'http' in the link -- being a new user, my posts are limited to just one link. Alas...)